# WPF RowEditEnding returns old values

Tags: c#, wpf

I bount an event of a dataGrid in WPF so I can keep track if a row was updated.

```
private void dataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    var text = e.Row.Item as Skill;
}
```

So my goal is to get the new values of the row if it has been modified but it only returns the old value. When I edit it the second time it returns the new value. Why is that?

Comment: I don't want to add a new item. I want to get the edited row with its new values.

Comment: is it you would like to do? e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.?(commit?) (this condition in your method)

Comment: What should I do? I don't get it.
The code from above only returns the row with its old values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is that?

The `RowEditEnding` event occurs *before* a row edit is committed or canceled: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.roweditending(v=vs.110).aspx.

What you really should do is to implement the [IEditableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) interface in your `Skill` class and handle the logic in the `EndEdit()` method.

The other option would be to explicitly commit the edit in your event handler:

```
private bool _handle = true;
private void dg2_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (_handle)
    {
        _handle = false;
        dg2.CommitEdit();
        var text = e.Row.Item as Skill;
        //...
        _handle = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also set the UpdateSourceTrigger property of the respective binding to "PropertyChanged"...